# Join two tables and show all combinations

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two models: Company and Contact.  A Company can have many Contacts.

```
class Company(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    companyname = db.Column(db.String())
    contacts = db.relationship('Contact', backref='contact', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, companyname):
        self.companyname = companyname

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)

    def company_contacts(self):
        return Contact.query.join(id = Contact.company_id)


class Contact(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contact'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String())
    lastname = db.Column(db.String())
    emailaddress = db.Column(db.String())
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, emailaddress, company_id):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.emailaddress = emailaddress
        self.company_id = company_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

I want to show a list with companies and their contacts in a template:

```
Company Name
First Name Last Name

Company Name
First Name Last Name
First Name Last Name
```

I was planning to do this with a join statement:

```
group = Company.query.join(contacts).all()
```

and have a for loop in my template iterate though this.  That didn't work.  How can I display the companies with their contacts grouped under them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a relationship between Company and Contact defined, so you already have the contacts grouped by company.  It would be more efficient in this case to not specify `lazy='dynamic'`, and your backref should probably be named `company`.

```
contacts = db.relationship('Contact', backref='company')
```

You can query with a `joinedload` option to build one query that fetches both the companies and their related contacts.  (You can't do this with `lazy='dynamic'`.)  In a view:

```
companies = Company.query.options(db.joinedload('contacts')).all()
return render_template('companies.html', companies=companies)
```

To display them, use nested for loops in your template.

```html
{% for company in companies %}
<p>{{ company.companyname }}
<ul>{% for contact in company.contacts %}
    <li>{{ contact.firstname }} {{ contact.lastname }}
{% endfor %}</ul>
{% endfor %}
```